# How to extract group id and artifact id from maven plugin?

Tags: maven, reflection, maven-plugin

I have a custom maven plugin which scan's for custom annotations in the source code.

ex:

```
test-parent-project
pom.xml

test-child-project1
src/
pom.xml

test-child-project2
src/
pom.xml

let's say if my custom annotation is found in test-child-project2, I want to retrieve group id and artifact id from test-child-project2

I am scanning the annotations using reflections.
```

Comment: A plugin works per module and not per project. Furthermore within a plugin you have access to MavenProject which you can get the information of the model which contains information about groupId/artifactid/version etc.

Comment: Thank you. Thats what i figured it out. looks like plugin will only have the information about the module and not the project.

Comment: I don't understand why you need the GAV from the project for annotation scanning?

Comment: we register the projects(modules) of the classes that are annotated with custom annotations.